# Number of connected components of the complement of a closed curve.

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness, geometric-topology

Let $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuous, closed curve (i.e. $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$). My question is about the number of connected components of the complement $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash\  \gamma$, where $\gamma$ just denotes the curve's image. I get the feeling that the number of connected components should be finite but I've been unable to proof it.

Comment: It's quite "obvious" that the number of connected components can be infinite. Just let their sizes go to $0$, place them next to each other, and go around them with a finite length curve.

Comment: How many times can $\gamma$ intersect itself?

Comment: Not even sure if this works. Try to find a continuous curve with $\gamma([0,1]) = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} B_{\frac1n}(x_n)$
where $x_n$ is chosen such that the balls touch each other...
@J.J. beat me to it ;)

Comment: I think because you are lacking the requirement of a *simple* continuous closed curve, to make this satisfy the Schonflies theorem, I think it must be possible to have an infinite number of connected components of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \gamma$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know algebraic topology so you be the judge of this. Isn't it possible to define $\gamma$ such that between $[1/2,1]$, I have a circle of radius $1$ centred at $(1,0)$, between $[1/3,1/2]$, I have a circle of radius $1/4$ centred at $(1/2^2,0)$,...between $[1/(n+1),1/n]$, I have a circle of radius $1/n^2$ centred at $(1/n^2,0)$.

As you see we are at origin for reciprocals of integers, and we have infinite components.

Comment: @J.J. Thanks got it. It needs to converge right? Is the rest ok?

Comment: For a visual, [Hawaiian earring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) (maybe not exactly the same radiuses and everything, but very close).

Comment: Fyi the curve length is $\frac{\pi^3}3$ and thus we can find a continuous curve to graph the described figure.