# Connected components of the complement of a closed geodesic on a hyperbolic surface.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, connectedness

Let $M$ be homeomorphic to a 2-sphere with a finite number $\geq 3$ of points removed. This implies that $M$ can be equipped with a complete, finite area hyperbolic metric. I imagine $M$ as an ideal geodesic polygon in the hyperbolic space with identified edges.

Let $\beta: [0,1] \rightarrow M$ be a closed geodesic in $M$ which we allow to intersect itself.

**What I want to show:** The complement of the image of $\beta$ in $M$ has only finitely many connected components.

As already answered in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869845/number-of-connected-components-of-the-complement-of-a-closed-curve/869851#869851) question, it is generally not true that the complement of any closed curve has only finitely many connected components.

**Idea:** So I was thinking that, maybe the property of $\beta$ being a geodesic implies that geodesic polygons completely bounded by $\beta$ can't have an arbitrarily small area. Then at least it would follow that there can only be finitely many connected components which are completely bounded by $\beta$ (this would actually suffice for my purpose).

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true and follows from the following very general

Lemma. Let $\gamma: [0, a]\to M$ be a geodesic in a Riemannian manifold ($M$ need not be complete). Then $\gamma$ has only finitely many self-intersections, i.e. if we define the subset $E\subset [0,a]$ consisting of points $t\in [0,a]$ such that there exists $s\in [0,a]\setminus \{t\}$ such that $\gamma(t)=\gamma(s), \gamma'(t)\ne \gamma'(s)$, then $E$ is finite.

Proof. I will give a proof only in the case when $M$ is a complete hyperbolic surface (which is what you care about) and leave you to prove the general result in case you are interested. Let $X\to M$ denote the universal cover of $M$ with the pull-back hyperbolic metric, which means that $X$ is the hyperbolic plane. Let $G$ denote the group of covering transformations for the universal cover $X\to M$. Then $G$ acts properly discontinuously on $X$. Let $\tilde\gamma: [0,a]\to X$ be a lift of $\gamma$; then $\tilde\gamma$ is again a geodesic. Since $X$ has no conjugate points, the map $\tilde\gamma$ is 1-1. Let $L$ denote the image of $\tilde\gamma$; it is a compact subset of $X$. Therefore, $t\in E$ if and only if there exists $g\in G$ such that $g(L)\cap L$ is nonempty and this intersection is transversal. Transversality (and the fact that $X$ has no conjugate points) implies that the intersection $g(L)\cap L$ consists of exactly one point. Therefore, cardinality of $E$ is at most twice the cardinality of the subset
$$
G_L=\{g\in G: gL\cap L\ne\emptyset\}.
$$
Since the action of $G$ on $X$ is properly discontinuous and $L$ is compact, the set $G_L$ and, hence, $E$, has finite cardinality. qed

In view of this lemma, the image of $\gamma$ in $M$ is a finite graph $T$ with geodesic edges. Then it is clear that $M\setminus T$ has only finite number of connected components (the closure of each component contains at least one edge of $T$ and closures of only two components can contain the same edge).